# Too many UIViews causes lag

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, drawing, lag

I am creating an app for practice that is a simple drawing app. The user drags his/her finger along the screen and it colors in a 100px x 100px square.

I currently achieve this by creating a new colored UIView where the user taps, and that is working. But, after a little time coloring in, there is substantial lag, which I believe is down to there being too many UIViews as a subview of the main view.

How can I, and others who similarly create UIViews on dragging a finger reduce the lag to none at all, no matter how many UIViews there are. I also think that perhaps this is an impossible task, so how else can someone like me color a cube of the size stated above in the main view on a finger dragged along the screen?

I know that this may seem like a specific question, but I believe that it could help others understand how to reduce lag if there are a very large amount of UIViews where a less performance reducing option is available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to draw each square into an image and display that image, rather than keeping around an UIView for each square.

If your drawing is simple enough, though, you can use OpenGL to do this, which is much faster. You should look at Apple's [GL Paint Sample Code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GLPaint/Introduction/Intro.html) which shows how to do this in OpenGL.

If your drawing is too complex for OpenGL, you could create, for example, a CGBitmapContext, and draw each square into that context when the user drags their finger. Whenever you draw a new square into that bitmap, you can turn the bitmap into an image (via CGBitmapConxtextCreateImage) and display that image an a UIImageView.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things that come to my mind:

1- Use Instruments tool to check if you are leaking any memory

2- If you are just coloring the views than instead of creating images for each of them, either set the background color property of UIView or override the drawRect method to do custom drawing

Comment: I am coloring in the views. But how can I pass the gesture recognizer's touch coordinates to drawRect? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the drawRect: method of UIView. You could create your custom UIView (you propably have that already) and override the drawRect method and do your drawing there! You will have to save your drawings in an array or another container and call the setNeedsDisplay method whenever the array content is changed.

Comment: You wouldn't call drawRect yourself, though, right? You'd want setNeedsDisplay.

Comment: Thanks! Yes you are right. It would be better practice calling setNeedsDisplay or setNerdsDisplayInRect: if you are alright with it just updating in the next drawing cycle.